# Cloud Run for Anthos is not available under deployment in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

I tried to add a cluster into a cloud run using Anthos. In all the tutorials and forums am seeing the "**Cloud Run(fully managed) and Cloud Run for Anthos**" options. But when i tried I am not seeing these options under deployment.

I even tried to add the cluster from the option "Cloud Run for Anthos". It is throwing the below exception
"Cloud Run for Anthos is no longer available as a GKE add-on, and is now installed using Anthos fleets: [https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/install"](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/install%22)

The add-on itself is not getting enabled. Even though I enabled the "**Cloud Run API**" still have the same issue am facing.

In the trial version, Anthos would not get enabled. or what am I missing here?

please help me to resolve this issue. I have attached the screenshot for the reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloud run (fully managed) and cloud run for anthos are two diffrent products even if they have the same name ,

Cloud run for anthos is basically knative (older version) , however cloud run (fully managed) is a new technology developed by google, from what i understand the backend is not kubernetes,

If you want to use cloud run for anthos you should create your cluster from the anthos interface and not from the gke interface and enable cloud run for anthos,

i recommend using knative instead because you get to use all the new features (node selectors...) witch are not included in cloud run for anthos (no roadmap information / realse dates )

https://knative.dev/docs/install/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will try and share an update with you.